# Are there any D&D 4e ritual card makers?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals

I want to make cards for my D&D group for our ritual spells. Is there a specific tool that anyone knows of that would help me with this? I already used tools like Power2ool and 4e power toolkit, but they only have at-will, encounter, and daily. There is no way to customize the headers.

If anyone knows of either a way to customize the headers in the tools that I already use or another tool that might help, I would appreciate it.